# Texture painting: cavity mask works in the wrong direction

Tags: texture-painting, masking

I am following this tutorial: BB- Paint and cycles cavity mask - YouTube.
At [12:05](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9Eg4wcqPHQ), he paints the object with the cavity mask option turned on, resulting in a nice gradient in the peaks and valleys.
I am trying to do the same, but my gradient is applied horizontally. Please see the picture below for more information.
[image]

Why is this happening? Thanks.

Comment: As far as can be seen, the texture node you show is not connected to anything. What are you trying to demonstrate with it?

Comment: @TheLabCat Thanks for your response. To texture paint, it is required to first define an image texture in the shader editor. I am currently in this phase. I later intend to use the painted texture as a cavity mask texture. (I will be using the same process in a sculpted model. The current model is used for demonstration purposes only.)

Comment: Hang on, if this is just an image texture being mapped onto a mesh, that means your UV map is turned the wrong way. You can fix this on the UV edit screen.